# One to One Chat Component with (PHP MySQL)

Tags: php

I want to add **one to one chat** component in my **PHP** based website with **mysql**. Just like a online help providing services. But I don't have any idea from where I can get such plugin/component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two better one.

https://blueimp.net/ajax/

http://www.phpfreechat.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try phplively

http://code.google.com/p/php-lively/downloads/detail?name=phplively-RC2.zip&can=2&q=