# Is there any 1 to 1 chat plugin/application available for symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I searched in google for a 1-1 chat plugin built for symfony 1.4 but could not find any altough I found  [sfKoreroPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfKoreroPlugin)  but it is a channel based chat. I am looking for 1-1 chat plugin for symfony 1.4 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin called [ChatPlugin](http://code.google.com/p/chatsrikanth/), a one year old one, that use a [jquery based chat](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/).

Comment: Sure, The author has not claimed its plugin but I will try to upload a new version of it once I customize it. Hope it should help everyone like me. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Far as I know there's no 1-1 chat plugin for symfony 1.4.

This bundle for Symfony 2.0, but can help you to write one for symfony 1.4
 [ServerGroveLiveChat](https://github.com/servergrove/ServerGroveLiveChat)

or you can try this question [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218849/one-to-one-chat-component-with-php-mysql)

Comment: To be more specific, In my project there are multiple sellers associated with multiple buyers. The client wants that the buyers should be able to chat with its associated sellers. Its kind of customer support live chat. Is it possible to built the same?

Comment: :you may join  chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11497/symfony1-4